# How send DM message to the author of the reaction?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I make the bot to send a DM message to the users who clicked the reaction?

```js
client.on("message", (msg) => { 
  if (msg.guild && msg.content.startsWith("!test")) {
    client.channels.cache.get("813782841187631126").send("Test-1")
      .then((sentMessage) => {
        sentMessage.react('811140592762486805')

        const filter = (r) => r.emoji.id == '811140592762486805';
        const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: 60000});
    
        collector.on('collect', (r) => {
          reaction.author.send("Test-2");
        });
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collect event on ReactionCollector takes two parameters; `reaction` and `user`. You can simply use the `send()` method on the [user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) to send them a DM.

Also, you should not collect the bot's reaction. You'll need to update your `filter` and add `&& !user.bot`, so you won't try to send the bot a message.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) =>
  reaction.emoji.id === '811140592762486805' && !user.bot;
const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
  time: 60000,
});

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  user.send('Test-2');
});
```